# Does rails have in-memory caching w/o using memcache or redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does rails have any in-memory caching option, other than me having to install memcache/redis?

I don't want to use the db or cookie based sessions.

How would I use 2 types of session stores i.e. cookies and say memcache/redis?   Would I have to create 2 API's for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html)? Check it out in the [web guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores)

Comment: Do note that this solution will not work when using multiple processes.